# Programmatically creating customisable diagrams on android

Tags: android, vector-graphics

I was wondering if there is a way to programmatically create diagrams.
For example - I want to create an image of a clock and be able to indicate to the computer what time I want to display on that. It could be that I want to illustrate '20 mins' on it. It should be able to portray that information on the clock.

Is there a way to do this? I think it would be a brilliant if something like this exists already. Or if someone could guide me towards making such a thing, that would be awesome too.

The diagrams (eg. clocks, graphs, world maps) should be able to portray information and change accordingly to adapt to the information that is entered.

I have browsed the web, but have only stumbled upon sites like RaphaelJS. But I don't think that solves my query.
Ideally, I'd also want to have the diagrams to be in my Android application. Is it possible?